# LinkedIn Swift session creation completion handler not being called

Tags: swift, xcode, linkedin-api

I'm trying to make a basic LinkedIn login for my app and obtain the user's *profile url.* I installed the LinkedIn SDK in my project. A couple of notes: In the info.plist, I have put the linkedin URL Scheme, the *LSApplicationQueriesScheme* and the *ExceptionDomains* attributes appropriately. In my app delegate, I have

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandle(url) {
        return LISDKCallbackHandler.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```

So, in one of my views I am trying to have the user login with linkedin. I put this code in to do that:

```
LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: { (returnState) -> Void in
      print("success called!")
      print(LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session)
    }) { (error) -> Void in
       print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

This code will bring the user to the linkedin app, prompt them to authorize the permissions for my app, and then returns back to my app. However, the success and error blocks never get called. I put breakpoints on both of them to make sure they just weren't printing empty strings, but they are just never called. I have tried waiting several minutes, and still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I too had this issue. Finally **solved** by doing this :-

In the **app delegate** part you need to implement this part of code

```
     if LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandle(url) {
                    return LISDKCallbackHandler.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
                }
        return true

}
```

in the following **delegate method**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
}
```

**insted of**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
```

***It should be like this***

```
  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

       if LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandle(url) {
                return LISDKCallbackHandler.application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
            }

            return true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe have a solution for you. Do you maybe have multiple apps on your phone that use the same Linkedin Application ID? If you do, you should just delete the other ones.

Comment: Sadly no, I still haven't found a solution